# How to get Row Id when RepositoryGridLookupEdit Value Changed

Tags: c#, grid, devexpress

I have a gridControl that has RepositoryGridLookupEdit, and I am using EditValueChanged event to get the EditValue. But, I dont know how to find which line has been changed?

repositoryLookupEdit returns the EditValue but I dont which row it belongs to. How can I get the Row Id?

```
private void repositoryItemGridLookUpCinsi_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var repositoryLookupEdit = (BaseEdit)sender;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit only the focused row. So, you can get it using the [GridView.FocusedRowHandle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_FocusedRowHandletopic) property.